# Less known hash functions producing 128 bit hash

Tags: hash

Good day.
While reversing a malware I stumbled upon a function producing 16 byte hash. I tried to determine which one is that by checking every function from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions). Nothing fits. So, there are two ways: a less known, or just custom algorithm.

Can somebody point me out where from can I get a more comprehensive list if hash functions?

Comment: Have you tried RIPEMD and RIPEMD-128? They where not in the [reference that you give as at the time you posted](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_hash_functions&oldid=630542332). Also, truncation of wider hashes are common. And a MAC with hard-coded key is common, and indistinguishable from a custom hash, even with a reverse-engineering of the code.

Comment: I routinely use SHA-256 truncated to 64 or 128 bits, it could also be one of the general ones with more or less rounds, or modified initial values

Comment: @fgrieu I checked RIPEMD, it's wrong algo.

Comment: @Richie Frame It produces exactly 128 bit hash, so no 'cutting' involved.

Comment: Have you checked if it is introducing some sort of salt? Or maybe doing several iterations?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not too sure this question is well-defined. CRC-128 could easily exist; and if I were writing malware I might use a weird-ass custom hash derived only loosely from a standard hash but with all S-box constants changed.

Comment: @fasmotol If no cutting is involved you should know more. How don't you have any info on the algorithm and still know no cutting is involved? Are you sure you know all the bits of the input?

Comment: @owlstead, the whole algo is a huge bunch of shifts, xor's, other logical operations and adding constants. All results are stored at buffer for hash (there is no intermediate buffer or smth), so I'm sure there is cutting involved. There are no cycles - plain block of instructions.

Comment: @fasmotol can you post a simple flow chart of what it is doing? in particular, which of 'shift' 'xor' 'add' and 'rotate' does it use and how many times it loops over that data mixing it are useful in fingerprinting it. Also, if it has its tables initialized with specific starting values searching for those in hex should turn up if they are mentioned somewhere online.

Comment: Those constant tables may be your best bet, you could compare them with existing tables. Trying to establish the exact input and trying everything known is another.